# Unix file size is bigger than real size

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, disk-usage

my Ubuntu Server (16.04) installation has a folder with 100 pictures in it.

Each picture is 100kb (true size) but it occupies 1MB (file size in disk), so 100 pictures are 100MB instead of 10MB.

I've read that it might be related to the filesystem format or the blocksize, but I don't know how to look for an answer to this problem, if such answer exist at all.

What I would like is for the files to only take up the space they need (100kb each) instead of 1MB.

Can someone help/explain? Links to online materials along with answers would also be very appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Can you find the answer in [Why are there so many different ways to measure disk usage?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/120311)?

Comment: A 10x ratio for files over 100k large sounds excessive though. How did you measure file size and disk usage? What's the output of `stat file.jpg` for a typical file?

Comment: For the record, the maximum supported block size for ext4 file systems (as was the default in 16.04) is 64KiB, so you can't get more than 128KiB disk usage for a 100000 byte large file there. I suspect you looked at the output of `du` for the directory, but missed either hidden files there or the fact that it also includes the disk usage of the directory  file itself.

Comment: Please post the output of `du -h yourdir/ ; ls -ah yourdir/`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks for your answer. The disk usage (10x) that I explained in my request comes from a windows computer, actually.

I have set up a SAMBA connection where some users drop their pictures (100kb each one, for example), but when they go to RIGHTCLICK->Properties with windows, they see that the file is 100kb but the actual file occupation is 1MB. That's why I thought I might be able to drop down the actual fle occupation somehow

Comment: Where do the files reside? On the Ubuntu machine on a ext4 fs and exported over samba to Windows users? Or on a Windows machine on NTFS and accessed from the Ubuntu machine using `samba`? Can you run that `stat` command mentioned above an include the output in the question?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas the files resides on an UBUNTU machine and Windows users access those files through SMB client, like so (\\[ipaddress]\folder\file)

Comment: You've still not posted the output of `stat` on one of those files nor clarified how you determine the disk usage.